# cx_Freeze: Python error in main script. Python 3.6 + cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze, python-3.6, traceback

I have problems with compilation python 3.6 to exe using `cx_Freeze-5.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`, help me please.

I have installed Cx-freeze from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze`

Then i started cmd and run this command:

```
    python setup.py build
```

`setup.py` file is below:

```
        import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    setup(
        name = "Check Telemetry",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Check Telemetry",
        executables = [Executable("excel_to_sqlite_xlrd-light.py", base = "console")])
```

Then i have something like this:
[image]

But if i run my .exe file i have problem below:
[image]

Screenshots with lines that have mistakes below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Have you got any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

seems that the program doesn't find the dependencies so add this (you have to add the missing dependencies (in this example i put os):

```
    # Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}
```

and then:

```
setup(  name = "Check Telemetry",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Check Telemetry",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("excel_to_sqlite_xlrd-light.py", base = "console")])
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Can you tell me please where i should put this string, in which file?     ->      
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}        <-

Comment: sure, in the setup.py file before the setup call. Sometime Cx-freeze doesn't recognise the library and you have to specify.  :) please vote the answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it! Sure, i will vote the answer, but i can t make it immediately, because i just registered and have reputation less then 15